# Append element to cell with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table with two columns and I like to append the same element to my second column.
I tried it with the following code, but it always just adds it to the first row.

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   var cell = row.cells[1];
   cell.appendChild(element1);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [clone the Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode):

```
cell.appendChild(element1.cloneNode(true))
```

`true` means deep copy here. If you don't create a new Node, it just moves to the new position of the DOM tree.

Comment: Just for clarification as to why. If you don't clone the node you are just moving the node within the DOM tree when you append it to different places which is why it only shows up in one place.